# Whiy git does not see an external repository located on github?

Tags: git, github

I created a repository on github. Completed all the steps to initialize and add your code

execute the command

```
 git remote add origin https://github.com/###/###.git
```

after run

```
git push-u origin master
```

I see the error

```
fatal: repository https://github.com/###/###.git not found
```

What's problem?

Comment: A space missing before `-u`?

Comment: What does `git remote -v` show? (Please edit the question: output will be too hard to read in a comment.)

Answer (score 0):

Since the URLs are case-sensitive, copy-paste the https URL string you have set as origin (as seen in `git remote -v`) in a browser, and double-check the repository is there.

Make sure also this is not a private repository, or one for which you have not provided (through a git credential helper) the proper authentication.